# express-session not giving any passport-user details

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am totally new to web development and i don't know how session works. I am using express-session i am getting multiple session ids but it doesn't contain any user info. Here are the session data what i am getting ,.

```
{
    "cookie": {
        "originalMaxAge": null,
        "expires": null,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "path": "/"
    },
    "__lastAccess": 1519657964928
}

{
    "cookie": {
        "originalMaxAge": null,
        "expires": null,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "path": "/"
    },
    "__lastAccess": 1519658181320
}
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe provide more code about how did you set up the session middleware. See the example: https://github.com/expressjs/session#example

Comment: `var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
   secret: '123456',
   store: new FileStore(),
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
 `  This is my code